# regex to match repeating string python

Tags: python, regex

I got strings which go:

> abc123abc123abc123
>
> abc123
>
> abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123abc123
>
> etc (varying units of abc123 which I don't know the length of repeat)

The task is to extract the first 1 and first a and the last c and last 3. Is it possible to do it with 1 regex and how exactly if it is possible? I kept count of the repeating units and based on the count I have been able to perform the task with a few regex, but would like to use one regex if possible. Thanks

Edit:
In the real situation. It is more like a:(a number)bc:(a number)1:(a number)23:(a number) etc and I have to capture the first a number, the first 1 number, the last c number and the last 3 number.

Jeff

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to find their positions? Because if you "extract" them, how does the first `a` differ from any other one?

Comment: In your examples, the first a is always at the start, the first 1 is always the fourth charachter, the last c is always the fourth from the rigth and the last c is the last character. So why dou you need a regex instead of x[0], x[3], x[-4] and x[-1]?

Comment: Yeah, please clarify your question a bit (with expected inputs -> outputs, and strings expected to *not* match (if any)..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easiest done using two regexen. `"^(a)bc(1)23" and "ab(c)12(3)$"`. It may be possible to merge these two, but the regular expression will get pretty unreadable.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of this? If the OP knows his string is a repetition of `abc123` then your regexes will invariably return `a`, `1`, `c` and `3`.

Comment: I modelled the answer after the edit by OP. My example was not intended to be literal code, but to match the question of the OP.